# Magento dynamic <select>

Tags: jquery, magento

I have been trying to create listing extension, that sub-categories of parent category through AJAX. But, for some reason alert('DETECT!'); is not being called not sure why.

Any assistance with this is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

.::JAVASCRIPT::.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[   
var reloadurl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('listing/item/categoryJAX') ?>';
var params = 'category_id=100';
alert(params);
$('select[name=category]').on('change', function(){   
    alert('DETECT!');
    var $select = $(this);
    alert($select);

    $.post(reloadurl, {category: $select.val()}, function(json) {
        $select.nextAll('select').each(function(i, select) {
            $(select).selectBox('destroy').remove();
        });
        if (json.length) {
            var $clone = $('<select>').attr('name', 'category').addClass('small');
            $clone.append($('<option>').val('').text('<?php echo Mage::helper('listing')->__('Select category'); ?>'));
            $(json).each(function() {
                $clone.append($('<option>').val(this.id).text(this.title));
            });
            $select.parent().append($clone).show(function() {
                $clone.selectBox();
            });
        }        
    }, 'json'); 
});
//]]>
</script>
```

```html
<select id="<?php echo $level ?>" class="listing_category" name="category">
    <option id="x" value="x"><?php echo Mage::helper('listing')->__('Select category'); ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you debug with firebug/developer console for js errors? Do you have also prototype loaded on the same page because you are not using jquery in noconflict mode and that might be the problem.

Comment: I debugged it, it looks clean.
I tried to use $j instead of $. I got error of undefined function $j(...

Comment: Add a `jQuery.noConflict();` at the end of jquery library if you include it locally or make another js file that contains this call and include it after the jquery include script. And use `jQuery` not  `$` or `$j`

Comment: Also wrap your code inside a jQuery(document).ready() and also I assume you have more options inside the <select> otherwise you couldn't test changing event if you have only one option.